# Why does my form with empty upload form take so long? What could be the reason?

Tags: php, html, file-upload

I have a form with a simple file upload input **like:**

```
<div class="contenttitle radiusbottom0">
    <h2 class="finfo"><span>Uploader</span></h2>
</div>
<p>
    Chose your file: <input type="file" name="uploaded_file" />
</p>
```

the rest as well, is a very simple form. Now when I execute (submit) this form it takes about 30 seconds to process it. Even when I don't choose any file to upload.

When I remove the file input from the form then it takes 1 second max. I add it back and it takes a lot of time again. The action page does not matter. What could be the problem?

**here is the complete form:**

```
    <div class="boxwhite">
    <form class="stdform" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action=""> 
        <div class="two_third">       
            <p>
                <label>Header</label>
                <input type="text" name="title" id="firstname" class="longinput" value=""/>
            </p>
        </div>     
        <div class="one_third">      
            <p>
                <label>Status</label>
                <select name="status">
                    <option value="1" <?= $content[status]==1?'selected':'' ?> >Active</option>
                    <option value="0" <?= $content[status]==0?'selected':'' ?> >Pasive</option>                     
                </select> 
            </p>
        </div>
        <br clear="all" />  
            <input type='hidden' name='parent_id' value='3' /> 

        <div class="contenttitle radiusbottom0">
           <h2 class="finfo"><span>Uploader</span></h2>
        </div>
        <p>
           Chose your file: <input type="file" name="uploaded_file" />
        </p> 
        <BR />
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add" class="" />
            <button class="cancel radius2">Cancel</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

(this files are on a windows server)

Comment: How does the complete html form look like - i hope you have one...

Comment: i have added the complete html above

Comment: Hmm what's about the `action` of the form? For example you can delete everything inside the form except the `<input type='submit'></input>` and `<input type='file'></input>` and submit again (only to test)..

Comment: Does the server side script throw any errors?

Comment: no there are no errors @bouscher.

Comment: i tried that @q0re but without any luck.

Comment: @Skeletor Well, maybe you should still put up the code where you process the $_POST['uploaded_file'], I'm quite confident that this is where something goes wrong, even if it's empty.

Comment: @bouscher i have added a 'upload.php', before which i use for the form action. there is a script that stores the form variables into the database. even in that way it does only work properly with our the file part. if i add it then the same goes there. slowly i think it has something with the hosting to do.

Comment: How does the PHP script look like? Do you connect to the database over ip or address? (for example: use `127.0.0.1` instead of `localhost`)

Comment: @q0re the database part down not have any problems. actually i test it using action="" so the form calls itself where is no other process. but even in this situation the page takes long to load. when i remove the file part then it loads in 1sec.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have moved the work to a linux server. Everything works fine now.